# how to remove the decimal digit using the javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to show the value **29.89** like this. but not need to show like that **29.0**, If after whole number is start with **0** means we need not show.

```
Example:

27.0 ==> 27 only

27.9 ==> 27.9 this is wright.
```

how to remove the **0** from first one using javascript

Comment: do you have already tried? show us some code

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of JavaScript:

```
alert(29.100) => "29.1"
alert(28.000) => "28"

document.body.innerHTML = 29.100 => 29.1
document.body.innerHTML = 28.000 => 28

etc.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4QYuR/

Answer (score 1):

Use following `parseFloat("YOUR-NUMBER")`
Here's an example how it works http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parsefloat

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the value is stored in string. Cast the value to float, and it should remove the point by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to Number object and use it anywhere in your page /project.

**Add function to Number object**

```
Number.prototype.myPrecision = function(){
    if(Math.round(this)==this){
      return parseInt(this);
    }
    else{
      return this.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
var n1 = 10.11;
var new_n1 = n1.myPrecision(); // This will output 10.11

//Other case
var n2 = 10.00;
var new_n2 = n2.myPrecision(); // This will output 10
```